# Iphone Calendar Application

Tags: iphone

i try to retrieve Calendar events between two dates. After that I try to delete all events. this program is working fine. The Events deleting process will take few second/minute based on number of events.

When device goes to sleep this application will work in background as usual. After coming to normal state(wake up) my application will exit. But, i did over come this problem, disable idle time.

But this same problem repeating when i press sleep/wake up button on the top of iPhone. How to over come this problem. What happens in my application, when changing state, any memory problem or any other...

Comment: Please post the error from your console here.

Comment: I don't think he is getting an error, I think he saying that his app significantly slows down after the phone goes into sleep and comes back.

Answer (score 0):

When the sleep/wake button is pressed, your application is sent to the background/changes mode to inactive. Check [UIApplicationDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. When this happens there are restrictions about your application doing background operations, which are described within the documentation.